# Disassociated posts are still linked from the network profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, network-profile, anonymous, top-network-posts

An *anon* user (which I assume stands for "anonymous")

[image: Anonymous, deleted? user]

doesn't seem to be very anonymous. This particular screen shot was taken from a [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/37092) which I found by following a link on a (very non-anonymous) StackOverflow profile:

[image: top network post]

Ironically it's on security.SE regarding privacy.

If it's really intended behavior that the post should be listed among the users Top Network Posts, I think it should somehow be clarified that the user is not in fact anonymous.

Comment: Where is the bug? How the user is not anonymous?

Comment: @ShadowWizard If I understand it correctly, the post was disassociated from the account, but there is still a link to the post in the network account. To actually check this we would need to know which user this is, but drawing attention to this case where the user intended to anonymize this doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @Mad maybe, it's really not clear from the title or question

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I went the profile page of a StackOverflow user (a very non-anonymous profile page) and found a link to the post made by an "anonymous" user. This is why I think the 'anon' user gives a false impression of that the user who posted this answer is anonymous.

Comment: @MadScientist, which is why I didn't include a link to the users StackOverflow profile. I'd be happy to share the user id with a mod.

Comment: @aioobe OK, so you should clarify this in the question, not just say "it's not working".

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I thought it was clear. (And I didn't say "it's not working".) I've updated the post.

Comment: I can reproduce this, it is a bug with the disassociation and the network account.

Comment: So it's a bug in the Top Network Posts section of the profile page, tagged properly now.

Comment: @Mad it's not network profile, it's ordinary user profile.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That section is fetched from the network profile, that is where the actual bug is

Comment: @Mad so the post is also visible in that user's network profile activity?

Comment: I'm not in a position to judge whether it's a bug in the Top Network Posts section (which I assume is a presentation layer thing) or if it is to be considered a bug in a lower level (like the content of the database). I'd prefer to leave this open to the devs to judge.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can see it in the "Top Answers" section of the network profile of that user, yes.

Comment: OK, one last tag. Now let's wait for a dev... :)

Comment: Hmmm... does the user have an answer on that question?

Comment: The link didn't lead to the question. The link lead to a specific answer to that question, and that answer was by an "anon" user.

Comment: I have seen this with a question on Workplace, too.  We had to delete the post even though it has highly-upvoted answers and we would prefer to keep it, because we couldn't deliver on the disassociation promise in the TOC.  That stinks; the people who spent time answering a reasonable question had their work deleted because of this bug.

Comment: @Monica sounds like a serious issue then, can't you bring it up  in the private chat room with SE staff? (Teacher's Lounge, if I'm not mistaken.)

Answer (score 18):

In the interest of getting this resolved, I'll set my embarrassment aside and provide a live example.

In the past, I've had a few questions disassociated from my SO account.

- [Serialization of RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075927/serialization-of-regexp)
- [Can you specify a sub-sequence for a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703052/can-you-specify-a-sub-sequence-for-a-table)

For some reason they still show up on my [SE profile:](https://stackexchange.com/users/309493/canon?tab=top)

[image]

Before anyone blames caching, these posts were disassociated *at least* several months ago.

Comment: There is also an example on The Workplace, currently deleted because of this failure but we'd kind of like to get the question (and its answers) back if we could.  CMs have attempted to fix it at least twice.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Maybe it'd be worth posting that you and other moderators have been forced to take such drastic action under [the linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258170/question-still-appears-in-my-top-network-posts-even-after-having-it-disassociate), saying something about the quality of the deleted posts e.g. vote score. Maybe that'd nudge the SE devs into actually fixing this.