# In the top answers list on my network profile, an answer deleted five years ago shows up

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, network-profile, top-answers

When displaying my own [top network questions and answers](https://stackexchange.com/users/2840114/jk-reinstate-monica?tab=top) on place 7 a [deleted answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/46614/is-a-world-with-an-average-temperature-of-34-c-habitable-for-humans/46617#46617) shows up.

I tested that this behaviour is the same when I am not logged in, so it has nothing to do with some earned privileges allowing me to see that deleted answer.

I consider this behaviour a bug: At least a user lacking the privileges to see this answer should not see it in the list of top network answers. I won't mind if it is hidden everytime or only visible after switching a toggle "show deleted questions/answers".

Comment: When was the answer deleted? If it was in the last couple of days, it's likely caching

Comment: It was deleted loooong ago (5 years)

Comment: Repro'd. I don't have any high-value deleted answers, so I can't test this on myself though.

Comment: Repro'd on your account and other accounts with highly voted deleted answers. The problem seems to be with top _answers_ specifically. I checked with top deleted _questions_ but they were not listed there.

Comment: Somewhat similar, with possibly the same, manual, solution: [Question still appears in my top network posts even after having it disassociated from my account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258170/271271)

Comment: Huh, same here: [this 1102-scoring answer to a deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334269/278659) still shows on my network profile.