# Top Answers contains links to deleted questions

Tags: discussion, network-profile

On this profile: https://stackexchange.com/users/42/saniul

The answers number 2, 3, etc. listed on this profile are deleted.

Should deleted content not be displayed in this list? Or displayed as text without links?

Comment: Also related, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258170, though that appears to be only for disassociated posts.

Comment: That user has no top questions at all, and the answers are deleted, not related to questions being closed.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar, thanks, I misread it. I don't understand the second part of your comment, the second link says “This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation”.

Comment: @A.L you mean **deleted**, not closed, I will edit. Closed question does not cause answers to get deleted, and it's also not relevant, answer can be deleted regardless of the state of its parent question.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar thanks, I see now. The questions were deleted but the answers weren't. And we can't see these top answers anymore.

Comment: @A.L - Anyone with 10,000 reputation can, although, they cannot vote on those answers to deleted questions.  Likewise, those answers, due to their age more than likely still count towards their reputation. Very suspicious every one of his highly rated answers were to questions that eventually were deleted.  That suggests a ton of his contributions were to questions that were so low quality they had to be deleted.